# Measuring end user latency or performance on the client side?

Tags: performance

Are there tools to measure end to end performance that the end user is facing ? Like bandwidth, latency, page load times in a way that it is non obtrusive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few tools available

- [Boomerang](http://yahoo.github.com/boomerang/doc/) by Yahoo
- [Episodes](http://code.google.com/p/episodes/) by Google

Comment: both the methods you mentioned work but they are obtrusive way ( scripts are getting injected in the page ) of measuring performance.  I was wondering if there are ways that help us using the event model of the browser to collect performance data points. thanks.

Comment: Some browser now do support WebTiming APIs https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html , but to pass that back to server you need to add custom script (Boomerang uses WebTiming wherever available).