# Best way to get client browser latency?

Tags: javascript, networking, client-server, ping

I have a custom web application, some clients are reported issue that they are not able to save the data.

So I would like to get connection speed between server and client machine...We have a PING command but we can't call it using javascript. I have tried to use IMAGE for that but I think this will not give accurate result.

So please let me know is there any other way to do this ?

Thanks,
Laxmilal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring end user latency or performance on the client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918021/measuring-end-user-latency-or-performance-on-the-client-side)

Comment: do you wish to measure latency or speed

Comment: I would like to measure latency.. but let me know what are the best way.,,